# How to make angular.js show the update with the data object update after some delay

Tags: angularjs

I am initializing a array of objects in the angular.js by loading them from the http service.

```
  <ul class="order-list" ng-repeat="catalog in catalogs">
                <li style="width:34%;" ng-show="{{catalog.ordered}}" ><span class="fa fa-money"></span> ORDERED </li>
  </ul>

   $scope.catalogs = [];
   $http({
      url: baseURL + "/orders/"+order.date + "?code="+order.code,
      method: "DELETE",
   }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
     $scope.catalogs = data;
           // first way
             _.each($scope.catalogs, function( catalog){
              console.log(catalog);
              catalog.ordered = true;
            })
          // second way
          setTimeout( function(){
            console.log("settimeout");
             _.each($scope.catalogs, function( catalog){
              console.log(catalog);
              catalog.ordered = true;
            })
            $scope.$apply();
          }, 2000)
   })
```

as in the code, if I used the first way, then html will immediately show the update, however, if I used the second way by delaying the update after three seconds, then the html doesn't show any updates, even I used $scope.$apply(); it just gave me a error of
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.17/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

How to do the update

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout()`?

```
$timeout(function() {
  _.each($scope.catalogs, function(catalog) {
    catalog.ordered = true;
  });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: I don't think it is the issue of setTimeout or the standard way $timeout. At least setTimeout executes after 2 seconds.